# How to step through an Android app from another country

Tags: android, adb, breakpoints, android-debug, android-debugging

I can't recreate the bug here and the app is communicating with a Bluetooth device that I don't have here. I want to be able to run the app and step through it line by line but I am in a different country so I don't have access to the phone and Bluetooth device.

Comment: you can try firebase crash reporting or analytics. the app will send the information (or crash log)  to firebase, and read your log from the console.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

Comment: The app isn't crashing though it's just not starting a service that it's starting here among other problems.

Comment: you can use remote ADB. But the target device has to have static IP, or port forwarded to it by a router

Comment: @user8612524 the app doesn't have to crash to send a custom log to the crash reporting. you can do a custom log (Custom logs provide insights into the behavior of your app and are collected by logging calls to the Crash Reporting SDK)